# How to rename the name of time series in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, rename, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Can Apache IoTDB rename the name of time series? Now I may need to change the name of time series later, but the data corresponding to different time series remains the same. If this time series name can be changed, how should I do that?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new time series and name it as you wanted. Then, you can use `select into` statement in Apache IoTDB, which copies data from query result set into target time series.

The statement may be like `select s1 into root.sg_copy.d1(s1), root.sg_copy.d2(s1) from root.sg.d1, root.sg.d2`.

By doing this, you can query all your needed data out and "rename" the time series by copying all data.